# Do I have to close all resources every time I use them?

Tags: java, resources, network-programming

I'm writing a chat application in Java for didactical purposes. Of course, I met a lot of problems as I'm not an experienced programmer.

Basically my question is: Do I have to close EVERY resource (BufferedReader/Writer etc.) after the use? Even if I know I will probably reuse it?

For example: the client that waits for the user to input text, can reuse the same BufferedWriter or has to create it every time the user inputs something and then close it again?

Comment: You can't use it after you close it. Therefore, if you're going to reuse it, don't close it every time you use it.

Comment: Only close your resources when you know you won't be using them again

Comment: I'd say "probably" isn't a good enough reason to hang on to resources. If you *know* you'll be using it the choice is obvious. You surely don't want to close it just to open it right away or in the very near future.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002896/is-closing-the-resources-always-important, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129088/are-resources-closed-before-or-after-the-finally

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check one and the same resource multiple times, just cloes it, when you do not use it anymore. You can use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) for this purpose:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
catch (IOException e) {...}
```