# Java read CSV file ,contents not write in new CSV file

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

```
package com;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class Sample2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        CSVReader csvReader = null;  
        String[] employeeDetails ;        
        CSVWriter  csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\sample\\myfile.csv",true));
        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\sample\\source.csv"));          
        try
        {        

            employeeDetails = csvReader.readNext();               
            while ((employeeDetails = csvReader.readNext()) != null ) {               

                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employeeDetails));                   
                    csvWriter.writeNext(employeeDetails);
                }               

        }catch(Exception ee)
            {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

I have my above java code
It read data from source.csv file and also display in the console .
It created myfile.csv ,but same contents it didn't write in the csv file
Anyone have any idea on this

Comment: Did you try to close your FileWriter and CsvWriter? Try using try-with resources

Comment: Not sure but may be you have to flush and close the writer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you don't close your output resources, try this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
String[] employeeDetails;

try (CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\sample\\myfile.csv", true));
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\sample\\source.csv"));
    ) {

  while ((employeeDetails = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(employeeDetails));
    csvWriter.writeNext(employeeDetails);
  }
}
catch (Exception ee) {
  ee.printStackTrace(); //perhaps you should also log the error?
}
}
```

Also take a look at this question [Is closing the resources always important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002896/is-closing-the-resources-always-importan)

Answer (score 1):

CSVWriter implements Flushable.Working Solution is already present in @Stephan Hogenboom's answer. I will answer why didn't it write in your case,

From the javadocs of `Flushable` interface,

> A Flushable is a destination of data that can be flushed. The flush
>   method is invoked to write any buffered output to the underlying
>   stream.

For performance reasons, all data is to be written into a Buffer instead of File temporarily. Once you call the flush() method, it flushes the data already present in the buffer into your file(this is where disk I/O happens, **not** when you call `writeNext()` ).

As mentioned on doc of `flush()` in `java.io.Writer`.

> Flushes the stream.  If the stream has saved any characters from the
>   various write() methods in a buffer, write them immediately to their
>   intended destination.

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: Thanks @StephanHogenboom :)

Comment: I must say javadocs has answers for anything just if we know to read it right! :P